# What is a good term to describe the last of a dying breed?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or short phrase that describes a person or animal that is the last survivor of a dying tribe/species?

I'm trying to use the word facetiously to describe something technical and dry. For example, "the XXXX of the widgets," or "XXXX widget," or "widget XXXX." So the more creative the allusion the better!

Comment: The Lone Widget Rides Again!

Comment: Does XXXX have to be in English? It can be a lot of fun in other languages too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here're a few

*The vestige of the widgets.*

*The vestigial widget* - People might not know what this means

*The last widget* - This is pretty common: e.g. The Last Samurai

*The surviving widget*

*The last surviving widget*

*The final widget*

*The widget, omega* - Requires some thinking to get the idea

Comment: +1 for **Omega**  And man!  _Vestige_ was the word _I_ have frantically been trying to remember!

Comment: Vestige is great. I was also thinking of the Omega Widget.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you could wow them with your literary knowledge and call it the [Chingachgook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chingachgook) of the widgets.

Comment: Not a terribly useful answer, but I had to upvote this anyway. :)

Comment: I ended up going with 'The Last of the Widgets', à la 'The Last of the Mohicans.' So I guess in some way I used your answer!

Answer (score 4):

I reckon the best term is:

> Sole Survivor.

As in:

> The sole survivor of the widgets

Answer (score 3):

How about the widget **Terminal** or **Terminus**?  There aren't really many single-word synonyms to that.  **Vestige** is a perfect fit, by definition, but not many people know what it means.

I like **Last Survivor**, but that's two words.  Or **Fading Legacy**.  Maybe even the **Lone Remnant**.  How about the widget **History**?

Comment: Two words is ok too. "Last survivor of the widgets" is pretty good. I suppose I could also use "the terminal widget" or "the ultimate widget" (although the latter might have a confused meaning).

Comment: Yes; I wouldn't advise "ultimate".

Comment: On this line, I believe "Terminal" is form you are looking for. _It was the terminal widget_.

Answer (score 2):

You want creative ... ? :-)
A certain biblical bias evident here :-).

- [Methuselan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah)  M. widget
  The very very very oldest. Last one left. Ancient beyond belief.
- [Antediluvian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antediluvian)   A. widget
  From before the (Noah's) flood.
- [Noachian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antediluvian)   N. widget
  The man himself.
- [Metazoic / Mesozoic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesozoic)    M. widget
  Choose any prior age, but Metazoic has a nice ring to it (may even be euphonic :-) ) and people tend to know what you mean without really knowing how old it really is relative to other classifications. (FWIW spans Triassic, Jurassic and Cretaceous - about 250 million to 70 million years ago.)

so

- [Cretaceous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah) Cretacean / Cretaceous  widget.
  Has a certain ring as it carries adumbration of being an, er, native of Crete.
- [" ... that Eden saw play"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah).   Widget that ... . 
  Tip of hat to "Morning has broken". Most will get the general allusion and many (some?) will also link mentally to the song.

Added:  Aim in most cases is to indicate that the widget was very old, so had been around from long ago, so was/is a throwback to another era.

Comment: All of these imply old, but not last. I would have thought the youngest would be the last.

Answer (score 2):

> bastion [ˈbæstɪən] n
>   1. (Military / Fortifications) a projecting work in a fortification designed to permit fire to the flanks along the face of the wall
>   2. any fortified place
>   3. a thing or person regarded as upholding or defending an attitude, principle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ultimate may also work for you:

> **Ultimate:** last; furthest or farthest;
>   ending a process or series: the
>   ultimate point in a journey;  *or* Being last
>   in a series, process, or progression

And if you need, *penultimate* is "next to last"

Comment: I'm afraid "the Ultimate Widget" would be misunderstood as "the best Widget possible" in this context.

Comment: @Rhodri, Context should clarify what meaning is intended. I still have to believe that this is the ultimate answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple biological reference is a population bottleneck (or genetic bottleneck); which a significant percentage of a population or species is killed or otherwise prevented from reproducing.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the self-explanatory "[I am Widget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_%28novel%29)"?

okay, it seems it's not obvious to the downvoters that this is an allusion to "I am Legend" (click on the link, please) so I'll suggest **"The Omega Widget"** or **"I am Omega Widget"**